# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error thrown after successful POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, cors

I am trying to set up an API to receive CORS POST requests, and I have reached the point where data is successfully being posted, however I'm getting an error reading "Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." which is causing the AJAX call to return an err state as opposed to a success state.

This is the AJAX call on the client side:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<my-server-url>',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    $('#contactForm').find('.submissionMessage').html('<p>Thanks for registering!</p>').show();
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    $('#contactForm').find('.submissionMessage').html('<p>Something went wrong with the form submission.</p>').show();
  },
  timeout: 10000
});
```

This is the API on the server side:

```js
function registerNewUser(req, res, next) {
  adminFunctions.newUser(req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.name, req.body.first, req.body.last,
    req.body.phone, req.body.company, req.body.stateOrProvince, req.body.jobTitle, 
    req.body.token,
    function registeringUser(err, success) {
      var jsonResponse = {
        error: err,
        success: success
      };
      var httpStatus = 201;
      if (err == 'Error: Failed to provide sign-up token.') {
        httpStatus = 401;
      } else if (err == 'Error: User with that email already exists.') {
        httpStatus = 409;
      } else if (err) {
        httpStatus = 500;
      }
      res.status(httpStatus).json(jsonResponse);
    });
}
router.post('/users', rateLimit, registerNewUser);

router.options('/users', rateLimit, function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400'); // 24 hours
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.end();
});
```

I have tried the response dataType to 'jsonp' in the AJAX call but I get a 404 error before it reaches the server.

I have also tried prefixing the url in the AJAX call with the cors-anywhere API but that also gives me a 404 before it reaches the server.

The only thing that seems to send a success response is when I enable the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin Chrome extension, which obviously can only be used for testing purposes.

Comment: Need to allow OPTIONS method. Suggest using a cors middleware pckge

Comment: @charlietfl — The OPTIONS method **is** allowed already. That's what the last 8 lines of the code in the question do.

Comment: @Quentin not in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` though

Comment: @charlietfl — It's not needed to allow a preflight OPTIONS request, only an explicit OPTIONS request.

Comment: Ideally you don't want to have the `*` wildcard on the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  You would want to list the specific domain doing the request.  By having the wildcard you're leaving yourself exposed to others making the request who shouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 6):

You have a bunch of function calls which add CORS permissions:

```
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

… but these are all only on the response to the preflight OPTIONS request.

They have to appear on **both** the preflight OPTIONS request **and** the response with the requested resource.

You haven't included them on the response to the POST request.

---

This is most easily achieved using middleware so you don't have to duplicate the calls to head the headers. The [`cors` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) is prewritten, mature, well-tested middleware you could use instead of reinventing the wheel.